# Why does MySQL ignore kana-sensitive when using the LIKE operator with a wildcard?

Tags: mysql, collation, cjk

When I search for `LIKE %カナ` it still brings up results for かな.

From the MySQL documentation (I'm on 8.0.26) under [Language-Specific Collations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode-sets.html):

> For Japanese, the `utf8mb4` character set includes `utf8mb4_ja_0900_as_cs` and
> `utf8mb4_ja_0900_as_cs_ks` collations. Both collations are accent-sensitive and
> case-sensitive. `utf8mb4_ja_0900_as_cs_ks` **is also kana-sensitive and distinguishes
> Katakana characters from Hiragana characters**, whereas `utf8mb4_ja_0900_as_cs` treats
> Katakana and Hiragana characters as equal for sorting.

Checking my column it shows the kana-sensitive collation:

```sql
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, COLLATION_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS;
```

| COLUMN_NAME | COLLATION_NAME |
| --- | --- |
| kana | `utf8mb4_ja_0900_as_cs_ks` |

Answer (score 1):

There are three(?) different pieces of code that MySQL uses for character comparisons: `=`, `LIKE`, `REGEXP`.  They are, confusingly, not identical.  And in some cases, they are deliberately different.

`s LIKE 'abc'` is turned into `s = 'abc'`, adding to the confusion.

A collation ending with `_as_cs` implies that `'e' <> 'E'`, but whether `<` or `>` applies is still honored.  This is unlike `BINARY` or `_bin` collation, in which cases it blindly checks the bits.

The collation you are using is relatively new; it is not older than 8.0.  If you find errors in the collation, please file a bug report at bugs.mysql.com and provide a simple testcase demonstrating the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For case sensitive try to use LIKE BINARY.

Example:

```
SELECT name FROM users WHERE name LIKE BINARY 'John%';
```

Comment: Note that I'm asking about kana-sensitivity. This works, but my question is why it doesn't work as-is with `LIKE` and wildcards since one of the operands is kana-sensitive as per column collation. Not using `LIKE` or removing the wildcard works as expected. The analogue test for case-sensitive works as expected as well without requiring the `BINARY` override.